# JQuery Validate submitHandler returns page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-post

I'm trying to validate & submit a Sign Up form via Jquery Validation. However, when I make the post call, I don't get the server response I expect, but the whole Sign Up page...

**Validateform.js**

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  $.post("signupscript.php", $('#signup-form').serialize(), function(data){
    //data is the html of the signup page
  });
}
```

**The actual parameters that are sent:**

- background: correct
- email: correct
- name: correct
- password: correct
- password_confirm: correct

**signupscript.php**

```
include("connect.php");

mysqli_query($dbhandle, "INSERT INTO users (name, email, background, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['background']."', '".md5($_POST['password'])."')") or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

$userid = mysqli_insert_id($dbhandle);  
//Setting a cookie

echo $userid;
```

I assume that somewhere in my code, the sign up page is requested and that answer returns sooner than the expected answer. Before using the validation plugin, everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It was caused by an external factors that I did not state in the question. I used a URL rewrite for "signup" that referred to "signup.php" - the signup page.

```
RewriteRule ^ccre/signup ccre/signup.php [NC,L]
```

Since I didn't close the URL to rewrite, it was also applied to "signupscript.php". I should have closed the URL like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ccre/signup$ ccre/signup.php [NC,L]
```